# Getting class name on runtime

Tags: java, runtime, agent

I try to get the name of a new object by using a classfiletransformer and a simple agent, but the only I can do is to get the class name, not the variable name. Is there any way to do that?
my example:
I've got a simple main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int z=1;
    if(z==0){
        Cube cube1= new Cube(2,3);
        System.out.println("Cube:"+ cube.area());

    }
    else{
        Cyrcle cyrcle1= new Cyrcle(2);
        System.out.println("Cyrcle:"+ cyrcle.area());
    }


}
```

and a classfiletransformer:

```
public class SimpleTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer{
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader    loader,
            String              className,
            Class<?>            classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain    protectionDomain,
            byte[]              classfileBuffer)
            throws IllegalClassFormatException {

      System.out.println(className);

       return classfileBuffer;
    }
}
```

I want to print print the "cyrcle1" object, but this way prints only the type Cyrcle.

Comment: What is an "object name"? How do objects have names? Do you mean *variable* name? And if so, a single object can be assigned to multiple variables and to collections, and so what would its "name" be then?

Comment: Have you tried soemthing like `Class.getName()` ?

Comment: I mean the class name for example: "Cyrcle cyrcle1 = new Cyrcle" the object name is cyrcle1 and its type is class Cyrcle. I want to get the cyrcle1 name. Unfortunately I tried Class.getName() and didn't work.